# Sending and receiving AJAX requests with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an AJAX request to a page to interpret some data, and if it complies with what i'm looking for, send another AJAX request back. Right now I can see the first request is being made, but I'm not getting one back

```
//message.php
<head>
<script>
function org_name(str){
    alert(str); //this alert appears, so I know the data is being received by this function
    $.get("common_functions.php", { group_name: str} );
}
</script>
</head>
```

Then, on common_functions.php I have a similar request back, however, I'm not sure exactly what the issue is. The alert box doesn't even appear so I'm confused as to why the console would say the request was sent

```
//common_functions.php

if(isset($_GET['group_name'])){
  ?>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert('common_functions'); //this does not appear
  $.get("message.php", { name: "test"} );
  </script>
  <?
}
```

When I open up the javascript console in chrome I see the request sent form message to common_functions, but apparently the request on common_functions isn't sending one back

```
//text from javascript console
Request URL:http://localhost/message/common_functions.php?group_name=test
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Does anyone see something obvious that I'm doing wrong or missing? If it makes a difference, common_functions is included in message.php because I do use some other functions from that page for my php.

Comment: Well you are not doing anything with the data returned by `$.get`

Comment: Can you post your PHP server side code?

Comment: @Gajotres  the php is already shown

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something with your data. Right now, you're making an AJAX call, and doing nothing with your data.

So something like the following would work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "common_functions.php",
    data: { group_name: str },
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).appendTo("head");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so assuming the data is sent to common_functions.php with this, will my code above work to retrieve this data? If so, how do I then send another request back?

Comment: You put whatever code you want to retrieve the data in the `success` function. This code replaces the `$.get` function you had above. If you want to send another request, just use `$.ajax` again.

Comment: Right, but I meant formatting wise what do I check for on common_functions? Would I just echo $_GET['head'] in this case?

Comment: @user1406951 I'm not quite sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "check for on common_functions"?

Comment: I'm still in the same predicament as before. I think it has been sent to common_functions, but when I try to display the data on common_functions, nothing appears.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20046/discussion-between-mc10-and-user1406951)

Answer (score 1):

Use $.ajax if you want control over execution states:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "common_functions.php",
            data: { name: "test"},
            success: function(r)
            {
                 // user r as output
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                 // error report
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
    });
```

In this case you can see if execution was successful or if error occurred.

Also you can use firebug add-on for firefox or chrome to detect if response was sent. There is also an excellent tool called [Fidler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which can give you much better overview over request/response states.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M) is an excellent tutorial for ajax debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` will strip out `<script>` tags. You can use another jQuery AJAX method `load()` that won't, or use `$.getScript`. If you need content and script you can do both by making an ajax request for the content, and in the success callback of that ajax, call for the script with `$.getScript`

`load()` replaces all the content in the specified selector

```
$('#myDiv').load('common_functions.php', { name: "test"})
```

Will take all the content of the php output and replace all the contents of `#myDiv` but will also run the scripts

Comment: So what would I check for on common_functions? Is it still a GET request?

Comment: I forgot to add data to send to server for `load()` . I just updated answer. Actually default will use POST in php

Comment: What I'm saying is, on common_functions what am I actually checking for? I see it's sending that div's info, but what is it represented as? $_GET['what_goes_here?']

Comment: if you send `{name: 'test`}` is received with `$_POST['name`];`. You really should study a few AJAX tutorials to get a better understanding. Their are lots of good ones with sample code included. Try Nettuts. They have great tutorials

Answer (score 0):

you may use a library that does that for you automatically, using http://phery-php-ajax.net
in your case, it would be

```php
function messages($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse;
  // return your messages
  return $r->json($messages);
}

function common($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse;
  switch ($data['group_name']){
    case 'messages':
       $r
       ->include_script(array( 
         'jquery' => 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'
       ))
       ->phery_remote('messages'); // load your messages
       break;
  }
  return $r;
}

Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'common' => 'common',
  'messages' => 'messages'
))->process();
```

on your page load

```js
$(function(){
  phery.remote('common', {'group_name': 'messages'});
});
```

you don't have to do anything else. btw, if you are including jQuery AFTER you are using `$.get()`, it won't work, obviously